# Our new colleague at work

Tags: cipher

So at work, we got this new colleague.
He's only been around for a few days, and the only thing that we know about him so far is that he likes to horse around a lot.
Today all colleague of our department got an email from him with the following text:

---

```
Qzox amuuzobmzv  

Pnfaz crnp np gv wnxpc /zzy N /mbuq unyz cm nfsncz ouu mw vmb mszx cm gv ,uoaz mf crz /zzyzfq  

N /nuu dz ,xmsnqnfe wmmq ofq qxnfyp wmx zszxvmfz /rm prm/p b,  

Pzz vmb ouu
```

---

Can you help me figure out what he wants to tell us?

**Clarification:**

Capitalization does not matter. For example "N" equals "n", it's just capitalized.

I used the american keyboard layout to creating this cipher (although I'm from Germany, so if you don't have one in front of you, I used the one provided by Windows and turned it into ENG(USA)).

---

I hope I didn't make any mistakes while typing this, since I made up the cipher myself (at least I don't know if something like this exists.. it might, I didn't double check that).

---

**Hint:**

> The clue to solving this is provided in the first paragraph / introduction.

Comment: Is your new colleague still on his probation period?

Comment: he is not his colleague after this e-mail. Very unprofessional.

Comment: I don't think you're dealing with a very stable employee here. He acts like he's king of the castle!! I think you should give him his final check and ask him to leave.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The cipher appears to function as follows:

> We draw the standard American Keyboard as follows, and for each letter, we go along a line as indicated (2 left, 1 up), (so that $D\to Q, M\to G$) assuming the board "wraps around" like a torus (so that $R\to X,A\to O$).[image]

In that case, the message decrypts as

> Dear colleauges,  Since this is my first week I would like to invite all of you over to my place on the weekend.    I will be providing food and drinks for everyone who showv up.   See you all.

Hint in the first paragraph:

> "Horse around" refers to the knight-like movement. "Around" indicates the wraparound property.

There's probably a typo in "prm/s", it should be "prm/p".

Comment: You got that really fast lol.. I thought I had been creative enough to make the puzzle last at least an hour or so.. Was it to easy? I'd like some feedback :) And yes, you're right, prm/s is a typo and should indeed be prm/p

Comment: @Radhato Another typo : it should be `amuuzoebzv` instead of `amuuzobmzv`. Feedback : maybe save your hint for later next time :). Also, it's easy to guess some letters (*e*, *l* for example) and deduce the words. But still, it is a fun and good riddle! What more could we ask for :)?

Comment: @Radhato It was a nice and creative puzzle, but you gave way too many hints. It would've been better if you hadn't mentioned the keyboard issue. :-)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback @IAmInPLS and Ankoganit I'll try to use that for my (hopefully) upcoming puzzles ;)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Actually, it should have been `amuuzomlzp`

Answer (score 4):

Considering the fix that @Ankoganit already gave to change `prm/s` into `prm/p` I came to this: (first turning everything to lower cases, and then when changing, using upper cases, to not do the same letters twice.)

> qzox = Dear
>
>  q = D
>  z = E
>  o = A
>  x = R
>
>  /EEyEfD = weekend
>
>  / = W
>  y = K
>  f = N
>
>
>  EsERvmNE = everyone
>
>  s = V
>  v = Y
>  m = O
>
>  YOb = you
>
>  b = U
>
>  wOOD AND DRnNKp wOR EVERYONE = food and drinks for everyone
>
>  w = F
>  n = I
>  p = S
>
>  WOUuD uIKE cO INVIcE = would like to invite
>
>  u = L
>  c = T
>
>  SINaE TrIS IS gY = since this is my
>
>  a = C
>  r = H
>  g = M
>
>  ,LACE = place
>
>  , = P
>
>  dE PROVIDINe = be providing
>
>  d = B
>  e = G

So I end up with:

> DEAR COLLEAUOEY
>
>  SINCE THIS IS MY FIRST WEEK I WOULD LIKE TO INVITE ALL OF YOU OVER TO MY PLACE ON THE WEEKEND
>
>  I WILL BE PROVIDING FOOD AND DRINKS FOR EVERYONE WHO SHOWS UP
>
>  SEE YOU ALL

This indicates another mistake. `amuuzobmzv` should have been `amuuzomlzp`.